# How to get the path of "audiodg.exe" Windows 7? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, exception, process, path

I was trying with the class "Process" but I always throws an exception.

The same happens when I try to get the path of other processes, processes such as: "System", among others.

I already tried with the class "WMI", but neither could get the path of the processes already mentioned.

I was thinking by the use of native APIs, however i think that's not a good idea, but no matter, if necessary will use them.

Does anyone know of any alternatives?

I ask this because, applications such as "Process Hacker" show the exact path of the processes that need get the path an example:

[image: Example 1 with the "audiodg.exe" process path]

[image: Example 2 with the "System" process path]

For this reason, I think it is possible to get those paths.

I apologize for my poor english but I think the point of the question is understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The System process does not actually have a file, so Process Hacker shows you the kernel file name instead. You can get this by calling [EnumDeviceDrivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682617.aspx) and then calling [GetDeviceDriverFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683185.aspx) on the first entry. Or, you can use NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemModuleInformation.
2. `audiodg.exe` is a DRM-protected process, which is why most programs don't work well with it. You can either open the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` access and call [GetProcessImageFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683217.aspx)/[QueryFullProcessImageName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684919.aspx), or you can use NtQuerySystemInformation with SystemProcessIdInformation.

AFAIK there is no way to get this information without using P/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shell command `where`, e.g. `where audiodg.exe` which should produce something like: `C:\Windows\System32\audiodg.exe`. You can execute it from your VB code and capture the output. Remember to handle "not found" exception.

How to capture console output:

[How to redirect output of console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13930157/how-to-redirect-output-of-console-application-to-textbox-control-on-a-windows-fo)

[Read console process output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996709/read-console-process-output)

Answer (score 0):

The following WMI query will provide the information you're looking for:

```
SELECT ExecutablePath FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'audiodg.exe'
```

You can perform the query in [wbemtest.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785775%28WS.10%29.aspx) to confirm the output is what you want.

Comment: In light of wj32's much better answer, please disregard my own.