# How to find IPV4 from hostname / worksation Name ijn VB.net

Tags: vb.net, console, ping, hostname, ipv4

Does anybody know how to grab the ipV4 of a machine connected over a LAN network in VB.NET? and output it via a textbox to look like a console window?
I have 3 text boxes, so 1 if for hostname/ws input and the second should show the ip address that had been grabbed and the 3rd to act as a console window to output CMD text

the code i currently have is:

```
Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        Dim textvar As String = txtWS.Text
        Dim Command As String
        Try
            Command = "Ping" & " " & txtWS.Text
            Shell("cmd.exe /k" & Command, 1, True)

            'Get IP Address of the Host
            Dim Hostname As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(txtWS.Text)
            Dim ip As IPAddress() = Hostname.AddressList

            txtIP.Text = ip(0).ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Unable to Ping Hostname or Workstation! Please try again, or try via IP Address." & vbCrLf & "Error: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)

        End Try
    End Sub
```

This works great for pinging but does not always return the right IP address i need to specify it to be the IPv4 every time and i want to output the console text in a textbox inside my app instead of the cmd window i have seen a few questions like this but nothing answered that incorporate these 2 functions

Comment: When it _"does not always return the right IP address"_ are you referring to that it returns IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: im not entirely sure its still something i am trying to work out, the network at work is really weird sometimes  it will grab the ip correctly and other times it returns another ip and if i check a machines ip via ipconfig its completely different i dont really understand how but if i can specify it to grab the v4 only then this issue wont be a problem

Comment: `but if i can specify it to grab the v4 only then this issue wont be a problem` - So you are saying that it returns an IPv6 address some times?

Comment: Have you [**placed a breakpoint**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx) in your code and inspected the `ip` array to see what IP addresses it returns?

Comment: yes sometimes it returns the IPv6 and other times it returns an ip that does not even relate to the machine (i know this sounds incorrect but its a strange network here) so when you ping a WS/Hostname in cmd it shows an ip sometimes this IP will still be a private IP that is on the network but will not be the IPv4 for the machine if i were to SCCM onto it, sometimes it will be another pc or just not work at all, then if i go to cmd on that machine and do ipconfing the v4 is completely different.
I have not done a breakpoint yet i was thinking maybe i just overlooked something

Comment: hoping that postin here someone could advise me what to change in the code

Comment: Well the `ip` array contains all the addresses (correct or not) that your PC could map to the workstation/hostname, so by inspecting it you might get a hint if any of those are correct. -- That your PC gets an IP to something else is not related to this code.

Comment: i have just found out my work has an ongoing dns issue this would be the problem its not the code! i thought there was something wrong with the network for a long time so i asked a manager today and was told the DNS is messed up which is why this behavior occurs, thanks for the help anyways! appreciate it, dont suppose you know who to display results in the textbox rather then cmd window ?

Comment: Either [**redirect the process's output**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996709/read-console-process-output) or [**ping it yourself**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.sendasync(v=vs.110).aspx).