# Running and Dump Command Line on VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i am new on VB.Net and dont know the methode for my purpose.

i have application called Monitor.exe running on command line(cmd.exe) with parameter

```
monitor.exe -o -i
```

and the output on command line have 3 line like this on success status

```
status device ready

device running 344 times

complete
```

or output like this if the process have an error

```
device error 3

please check the connection cable
```

My purpose is :

1. i want run this command line running with ordinary cmd.exe without showing the cmd.exe window with button
2. then i want to grab the result like "complete 344 times" when the status is complete  as label text
   or grab "error" word when the status have and error as a label text

your help would be very appriciate.
thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read Console Process Output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996709/read-console-process-output)

Comment: Set 'ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle' to 'ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden' and check : [Get the output of a shell Command in VB.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809194/get-the-output-of-a-shell-command-in-vb-net)