# How to redirect Output of console application to Textbox control on a windows form at run time using vb.net 2012

Tags: vb.net

Team,

I have an third party application which actually is a telephonic messaging server and exchange messages between all connected clients and other servers. This messaging server keeps running for several days and even for moths. This is entirely a console application and do not have any GUI. Even to manage the internal operations of this server, there is another tool which is a console based application again. I would like to prepare a GUI to start, stop and restart this server in VB.Net 2012. I have managed to,

1. Create the process instance of this server
2. Launch the Server with appropriate parameters and keep it running. Below is some sample code from my application to launch the server,

   Private Sub Server_Start_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Server_Start.Click
       Dim parameter, server_admin_path As String
       server_admin_path = "D:\Voice_App\DataMessage\MessageServer.exe"
       parameter = " -properties " & """" & " D:\Voice_App\Config\message.prop"

   ```
   Dim proc = New Process()
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = server_admin_path
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = parameter
   ' set up output redirection
   proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
   proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
   proc.EnableRaisingEvents = True
   Application.DoEvents()
   proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
   proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
   ' see below for output handler
   AddHandler proc.ErrorDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
   AddHandler proc.OutputDataReceived, AddressOf proc_OutputDataReceived
   proc.Start()
   proc.BeginErrorReadLine()
   proc.BeginOutputReadLine()
   'proc.WaitForExit()
   Server_Logs.Focus()
   ```

   End sub

This code launches the message server very well. The message server is now started and it is producing log traces on the console after specific time of interval say 30 seconds and this will be continue till message server is not stopped by administration tool. So now what I want is to capture every single line that is being produced by my server on its console and paste that line on to the Textbox I have on my windows form.

I got below code which gives me that every line as and when produced,

```
   Public Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As                     DataReceivedEventArgs)
    On Error Resume Next
    ' output will be in string e.Data
    ' modify TextBox.Text here
    'Server_Logs.Text = e.Data  ` Does not display anything in textbox
    MsgBox(e.Data) 'It works but I want output in text box field
End Sub
```

P.S = My application will be handling more that one such servers and I don’t want users to have every message server instance open on their taskbar as console window and they are scrolling long log traces. I searched lots of threads here but nothing worked for me in above scenario. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this since very long time and this is now a showstopper!!!!

Comment: So basically Textbox.Text &= "\n" & e.Data then? Or am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: Thanks WozzeC for your suggestion but I tried everything with that damn Textbox but had no luck. There must be something different. Thanks for your inputs though!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to make a call from a thread that is different from the thread the form is on. The events raised from the Process class will not be from the same thread.

```
Delegate Sub UpdateTextBoxDelg(text As String)
Public myDelegate As UpdateTextBoxDelg = New UpdateTextBoxDelg(AddressOf UpdateTextBox)

Public Sub UpdateTextBox(text As String)
    Textbox.Text = text
End Sub

Public Sub proc_OutputDataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataReceivedEventArgs)

    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(myDelegate, e.Data)
    Else
        UpdateTextBox(e.Data)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, user409762!!

It is working exactly the way I wanted. Thanks for noting my mistake out.. Thanks

Comment: This works perfectly with one exception.  I'm appending text to a rich text box, which works using .appendtext() but when it just adds one line to the end of the next, if I try putting a VBNewLine or VbCrLf or Environment.NewLine after the text I'm appending, I end up with an extra line between each 'output' line.  Can anyone help with that.  I figured it might be easier to ask here than start a new question.

Comment: VBNewLine = chr(13) + chr(10) = vbCr & vbLF
try to use vbCR only or vbLF only